# MySQL Between by using replace

Tags: mysql, select, join, between

I have 2 tables

- Group
- User

Group table has

- ID
- Age (this is range. 23,40) means 23 to 40
- Gender

User table has

- ID
- Age
- Gender

I want to check if user's age is valid for his gender's group
I wrote this query now

```
Select user.id, group.id as 'GroupID', Replace(group.age, ',', ' and '),
if (user.age between Replace(group.age, ',', ' and '), 'Valid', 'Invalid')
from user inner join group on group.gender = user.gender
```

this is generating query error on if (user.age between , Replace(group.age, ',', ' and '), 'Valid', 'Invalid') clause

but if I run this as

```
Select user.id, group.id as 'GroupID', Replace(group.age, ',', ' and ')
from user inner join group on group.gender = user.gender
```

this runs fine and produces out like 
    1 | 1 | 20 and 40

why this replace not working in between clause
is there any other way to check if value is between a comma separated column value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
user.id, 
group.id as 'GroupID', 
replace(group.age, ',', ' and '),
if (user.age >= CAST(SUBSTRING(group.age, 1, 2) AS UNSIGNED) and user.age <= CAST(SUBSTRING(group.age, 4, 2) AS UNSIGNED), 'Valid', 'Invalid')
from user 
inner join group 
on group.gender = user.gender
```

Comment: Syntax Error, anyway will this work if gender.age value is 10,20 and user.age is 15? I guess no, I need to check whether 15 is between 10 to 20

Comment: Yes, actually the syntax error, I understand now, becauase replace(group.age, ',', ' and ') will still return a string, and I guess that user.age field is an integer. I'm thinking of a better solution and will edit the query.

Comment: I changed it, let me know if it's OK. 
If the value in group age is anytime less than 10 or more than 99, then a more generic approach will be needed, because this SUBSTRING function is always taking two characters.. Also you will need to check what is the exact data tpye of the user.age field and that one has to be used in the CAST (I wrote it with UNSIGNED integer type)

Comment: thanks, this has a limitation of 2 digit age, what about 100?
I used

user.age >= LEFT(group.age, LOCATE(',',group.age) - 1)